# Grails rendered content accessing id elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails, grails-2.0

AJAX content is being rendered with a `remoteLink` function inside the form to populate a accordion (*just a little background info*).

The `function attatchEmail(test)` which is being called on the double-click of each paragraph content of the JQuery Accordion widget. This is what happens running the function... [Screenshot of 1st alert](http://d.pr/i/ZI9R) & [Screenshot of 2nd alert](http://d.pr/i/G7hu).

Is it not possible to select the paragraph and get the contents from the paragraph like below?

(I have tried changing `.val` to `.html` and `.text`. I have also tried `$('#'+testingID)`)

**_form.GSP**

```
function attatchEmail(test) {
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    var testingID = test.id;
    alert(testingID);
    var testingValue = $(testingID).val();
    alert(testingValue);
    });
};
```

**_contactListAjax.GSP**

```
<g:each in="${contactList}" status = "i" var="contact">
    <h3><a href="#">${contact.contactSurname +',  '+ contact.contactForename}</a></h3>
    <div><p id="contact${contact.id}" ondblclick="attatchEmail(this)">${'Email:  '+contact.email}</p></div>
</g:each>
```

Run out of avenues to explore, I'm sure I've done something simple like this before perfectly fine :/

**See two screenshots please for better insight, thanks**

Comment: Why do you have a document ready function inside a function?

Comment: It was just a test, I tried to explore any possible weird goings on. I meant to remove that before I posted, my bad Gregg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like you're using jQuery but it also looks like you're not really buying into the jQuery methodology.  Mixing behavior with markup is not really considered a good practice these days, especially when using a library like jQuery.  I'm not sure of your exact issue but I would recommend changing it to something like the following:

```
<g:each in="${contactList}" status = "i" var="contact">
    <h3><a href="#">${contact.contactSurname +',  '+ contact.contactForename}</a></h3>
    <div><p class="contact-email" data-id="${contact.id}">${'Email: '+contact.email}</p></div>
</g:each>

$(function() {
   $("body").on("dblclick", ".contact-email", attachEmail);
});

function attatchEmail(event) {
   var $element = $(event.target);
   var id = $element.data("id");
};
```

This should help fix any issues with dynamic rendering because of the way the [jQuery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function works.

Comment: I believe it's now working, that's smashing... I'm just going to quikcly test again

Comment: You should read the link for jQuery on and then you'd understand how that works.  If it isn't working for you, you're doing it incorrectly.  I have quite a bit of code like this working flawlessly for dynamic content.

Comment: The javascript I provided doesn't need to be loaded each time the form is loaded.  It only needs to be loaded once, so put it in a script file that is global to your app and only loads once.

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake on my part Gregg, I do apologise... I'm currently looking into the on function still learning JQuery & JavaScript as I go along with the odd thing here an there.

Comment: I do have one quick question for you, if I could be so cheeky... now that I have the `id` of a contact, I wanted to actually grab out the email address. 
So to try this I've simply used the `(id).html();` and tested with alert and it gives `null` ... when it obviously exists as you can see in the screenshots in the initial question above, quite confused :S

**edit** also tried `('#'+id).html()`

Comment: Smashing ! Thank you Gregg :) Happy New year